# PHP returning error500

Tags: php, rss

This code return an error500 and have no clue why

```
<?php

$url = "https://www.idownloadblog.com/tag/iphone/feed"; // url to parse
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url); // XML parser

// RSS items loop
echo $rss;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Becuase simplexml_load_file is to load a file not an URL

http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Comment: No, that is actually not true. Most file loading functions in PHP can very well also load a document from an URL. And actually, that is clearly mentioned in the documentation you yourself linked...